# Data selection/Row selection

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, amazon-redshift

I have a scenario where I have to write a SQL query where I consider only the negative values for selected date.

how to achieve the output

[image]

what i want is to convert all non negative numbers to zero for a particular date. In this case 2021.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for a conditional `sum`. The logic is to put a `case` expression within the aggregate function, like so:

```
select
    sum(case when "2020" < 0 then "2020" else 0 end)  result_2020,
    sum(case when "2021" < 0 then "2021" else 0 end)  result_2021
from mytable
```

It is quite unusal to have columns with all-digits names such as `2020`, so I wonder whether what you are showing is your actual sample data or the results of an intermediate query (in which case, further optimizations may be possible).

---

**Edit**

The above answers the original version of the question. This answers the edited question:

You can use a `case` expression to turn positive numbers for date `2021` to `0`:

```
select 
    fab, 
    date, 
    case when output > 0 and date = 2021
         then 0
         else output
    end output
from mytbale
```

Comment: Hi GMB, its a sample data, what i intend is if one value is <0 then the output is that negative number and if both are negative then output is the sum of the negative values

Comment: @Sam: ok. This query will do what you want.

Comment: Hi GMB , i have edited the question, what i want is convert all the non negative numbers to zero for a date

Comment: @Sam: it is not a good practice to change the question after answers were posted... Anyway, I added a second part to my answer that should do what you ask for now.

Comment: Sorry @GMB , i will keep this in mind.  I have many values with dates , i am comparing S and N output for a particular date. When one of these is negative the other  is kept 0.

Answer (score 0):

Say if you have a table like below

[image]

I think you are looking for something like this

```
SELECT id,
    year,
    (case when (a>0 and year = 2021) then 0 else a end) as a_filtered,
    (case when (b>0 and year = 2021) then 0 else b end) as b_filtered 
FROM `table_name` 
WHERE 1
```

The output will be the following.

[image]

Comment: Hi Tawad, sorry i had to edit my question for clarification

Comment: So in your case you converted all 2021 non negative numbers to zero?

Comment: yes, say if for a year S= -80 and N= 30 , then i want to convert it into S=-80 and N= 0

Comment: How about `update table_name set N=0 where year=2021 and N < 0` ?

Comment: I cant do that , i need to do via the query, its a result of a query whse example i showed. .

Comment: So you only need to show the modified data not update it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214780/discussion-between-sam-and-md-tawab-alam-khan).